# Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable. How to solve? Do I need to solve?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have the following code which gives the warning in the title. I am pretty sure I have done something like this before but it didnt give any warning. I would like to ask two things of those posting. 1) What here would cause a problem? 2) Does it need to be fixed?

The reason I ask is that this code works fine as I expect it to so clearly this warning is not causing an issue. I cannot stand to have warnings etc in my code though and so would like a solution to this but I also want to know why this warning occurs and if it is harmful in any way.

Code:

```
 public class AttributeType
 {
      private string m_attributeNameField;

      public string AttributeName
      {
          get { return m_attributeNameField; }
          set { m_attributeNameField = value; }
      }
 }

 private StandardResponseType ValidateAttributes(string featureType, IEnumerable<AttributeType> attributeList, string userCategory)
 {
       StandardResponseType standardResponse = 
       new StandardResponseType(DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "RWOL_UTILS.Get_Item_Attributes", "", "OK");

        if (attributeList.Any())
        {
            foreach (AttributeType attribute in attributeList)
            {
                if (attribute.AttributeName == null) continue;
                {
                    //do stuff
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            standardResponse.Message = "Error: No attributes passed in the list. ValidateAttributes().";
            standardResponse.ResponseCode = "FAIL";

            return standardResponse;
        }
}
```

EDIT: There is more code in the method but it doesn't have a bearing on this issue.

UPDATE: I had to add the follwing code to make this work. Why is it more efficient to add this? If I have to count and read the new list then what is the difference between doing that and doing it on the original item? The list is only ever passed once. I could understand this issue if the list was populated within the method but is isnt. It is just passed in already filled.

```
List<AttributeType> newlist = attributeList.ToList();

if (newlist.Count() != 0)
{
    foreach (AttributeType attribute in newlist)
............
```

Comment: what type is `attributeList`?

Comment: Don't see the full code, but you don't cause any side effect. Have you tried filter it with LINQ?

Comment: I dont know any LINQ so wouldnt like to mess about with it to be honest. I will post more code.

Comment: @DanielA.White The attributeList is  IEnumerable<AttributeType>

Comment: I have added an update. Is there not a more elegant way of solving this issue than putting the list inside another list? I would have thought that I would only have my list passed into the method once so why does counting it and reading it cost any more than reading it into another list and doing the same with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The possible problem depends on where your `IEnumerable` comes from. Some data sources might only allow for a single enumeration or they might be expensive (maybe some database query), which would be already started by `attributeList.Any()`.

You can just remove the `Any()` check, because if there are no elements in your `IEnumerable` , your loop won't run anyway (assuming your example shows the complete picture and there is no other logic dependent on the check).

EDIT: Based on your edited question, you cannot remove the check. But, you can use `attributeList.ToArray()` to convert your `IEnumerable` to an array which you then work with and get rid of the warning.

Comment: Tried using .ToArray() and .ToList and neither rids me of the issue.

Comment: @CSharpened You should store the result of one of those calls in a appropriately typed variable and then use that variable for both the check and the loop. Also, you don't need Any() then, but the Length (array) or Count (List) properties.

Comment: I have now added the code and it does work so thankyou. I was wondering if there was not a more elegant solution though. Do you think there is an issue with me using IEnumerable?

Comment: @CSharpened I don't think it's an issue by itself, the compiler just cannot predict which data source the IEnumerable has, so its warning is not unreasonable. You could also change the signature of your method to expect an array, but of course that's not always possible. Or use a bool to keep track of whether any items were processed. That would also cover the case where all AttributeNames are null (which you might or might not want to handle the same as if there were no AttributeTypes).

Comment: Yes I previously had tests for both null and also no count but removed the null when I spotted this issue. I see so it is more an issue that IEnumerable cannot be predicted rather than an issue in the way I am using it?

Comment: @CSharpened IEnumerable is just an interface that specifies that it can be enumerated. What happens at each iteration is completely unknown to the compiler. Of course, by expecting an IEnumerable, you also explicitly allow for this kind of flexibility. Because of that, i think the compiler is right. Regarding usage, i would go with changing the parameter to an array or with the flag approach.

Comment: Thanks. That is pretty much what I wanted to know.

Comment: It's too bad that C# `foreach` and vb.net `For Each` weren't designed so they could accept either an enumerable object or an enumerator, since there are situations like reading items from a queue where one might logically want to use `foreach` with a source that can only supply items once, but such items probably shouldn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 6):

Just get rid of the `if`; it's useless.

The warning is from Resharper, and it's warning you that if `attributeList` is expensive to enumerate, your code will be slow. (because it enumerates once for the `Any()` and a second time for the `foreach`)

Comment: So how would you suggest taking actions in case the foreach is empty? A bool indicator is ugly. What else have you got? (I'm not in favor of the Any() at all - I'm just saying lets think of the best solution)

Comment: I had initially used an if(count>0) to test if any were present but changed to Any() by resharper.

Answer (score 1):

The cause is that call `attributeList.Any()` which starts down the `attributeList` and as soon as it finds something it enters your for loop.  Then you do a foreach over the list, which again traverses the entire list.

You actually don't need the `.Any()` here as doing a foreach over an empty enumerable will not cause any problems, it just won't return anything.

Where you could get into a problem is if you were pulling data from a DB and inside a foreach made another call to the enumeration, since it's deferred execution you could get different results back that you aren't expecting on your second call.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing `attributeList` is an `IEnumerable<>` of some sort. `IEnumerable` objects, unlike `List`s, aren't necessarily a list of objects in memory, and might be bound to complex logic that queries a DB for them every time you iterate over it. Using C#'s `yield return` commands can also return an `IEnumerable` that has logic bound to every iteration.

Because of this behavior, the warning tells you that you might be iterating over your attributes more than once, a potentially expensive operation. Once during the `Any()`, and once over the `foreach`. It's true that in this case the `Any()` is superfluous, but in general you can avoid this warning by calling `ToList()` or `ToArray()` on your `IEnumerable`, thus performing the enumeration *once* and storing the result in an explicitly allocated list/array. Now you can go over it again and again with no performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check .Any()
here is the fixed code :

```
        bool empty = true;
        foreach (AttributeType attribute in attributeList) 
        { 
            empty = false;
            if (attribute.AttributeName == null) continue; 
            { 
                //do stuff 
            } 
        } 
        if (empty)
        {
          {  
              standardResponse.Message = "Error: No attributes passed in the list.       ValidateAttributes().";  
              standardResponse.ResponseCode = "FAIL";  

              return standardResponse;  
          }  
        }
```

Checking .Any() can cause an enumeration, That's why you get a warning => First enumeration "Any" to check if it is empty and a second enumeration "foreach".

If the type of attributeList allows it, you can check Count or Length :

```
    if (attributeList.Count != 0)         
    {         
        foreach (AttributeType attribute in attributeList)         
        {         
            if (attribute.AttributeName == null) continue;         
            {         
                //do stuff         
            }         
        }         
    }         
    else         
    {         
        standardResponse.Message = "Error: No attributes passed in the list. ValidateAttributes().";         
        standardResponse.ResponseCode = "FAIL";         

        return standardResponse;         
    }
```

Comment: I will add more code. The If is there to test whether any attributes are passed.

Comment: .Count does not solve the issue. The If(...Any()) line was previously the one you state. I changed it after a suggestion from ReSharper. Probably not a good idea to listen to ReSharper lol

Comment: .Count() is worse than .Any() as it does a complete enumeration but .Count or .Length property is usually OK (you may want to check that implementation is O(1)).

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to solve it. However, if your `if (attributeList.Any())` doesn't have an `else`, you can eliminate it completely, which will get rid of the warning. In fact, your code sample can be replaced with:

```
foreach (AttributeType attribute in attributeList.OfType<AttributeType>())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Have added more code. If does have an else used to report that no attributes were sent with the request.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to allow you do this, which it prettier:

But anyways, when you call .Any() it only iterates over the first item, so it really isn't THAT bad.

This way is just more readable, although kinda ugly in the background (still efficient).

```
        bool any;

        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Loop(out any))
        {
            // Do loop logic
        }

        if (!any)
        {
            // Handle empty IEnumerable
        }
```

How?!:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Loop<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, out bool any)
    {
        var b = true;

        var enumerable = source.Loop(() => { b = false; });

        any = b;

        return enumerable;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> Loop<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action anySetter)
    {
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

        enumerator.Reset();

        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            anySetter();
            yield break;
        }

        do
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        } while (enumerator.MoveNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I searched for this exact problem for my query to dataset, I went to add .Any() and found I could add .AsQueryable() to the end of my selection and my foreach works with it. .AsQueryable converts a generic IEnumerable to a generic IQueryable.